# Getting error in Sliding Tab and AppCompatActiivty theme in android

Tags: android, android-theme, pagerslidingtabstrip, android-tablayout

I am using **AppCompatActivity** with some actionbar buttons ,in **First Activity** of My app.

from **Second Activity** i am using **Sliding Tabs**.

My theme.xml(Theme 1)

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

        <!-- theme customizations -->

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/easy</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/easy</item>


           <!-- Size Of Action bar-->
         <item name="actionBarSize">55dp</item>


    </style>
```

**First Activity** Working fine. Using Above theme But

Error in My Sliding Tab page

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingtab}:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. 
Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

My theme.xml(theme 2)

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

</style>

<style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Both of these are needed -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

If i am using above theme, **Sliding TAB** page Working Fine, but My **first Activity Showing NPE.**

**Problem:**

1.i want custom theme for **first activity**,

2.also i need **sliding Tab in Second Activity**

How to fix this problem please help me .

**EDIT :1**

Added Oncreate Method

**My Sliding Tab Oncreate**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.find_stores_0_tabview__landing);

        // for ActionBar back button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Initilization

        // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles
        // fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles,Numboftabs);

        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true,
                                        // This makes the tabs Space Evenly in
                                        // Available width

        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });

        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);



        // End OF OnCreate

    }
```

Comment: Provide please code of your onCreate methods

Comment: first activity oncreate or Sliding tab?

Comment: i added my on create

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you define different theme for them.

and I think the problem wasn't caused by the Sliding TAB , 
check your code again.

your first Activity theme :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

your second Activity theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".first Activity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
<activity android:name=".second Activity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"/>
```

Comment: ya ,problem is not in my sliding tab, i want to assign theme for first activity no actionbar for sliding Tabs. how to do this.

Comment: name="NoActionTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: i already mentioned in my question, If applying this code definetly Sliding Tab will work but, i need First Activity with actionbar.

Comment: in my Firstactivity i am having menu items, so i need Actionbar.

Comment: I do not understand why you want to use single theme for your different require. you can define two theme for their ,and assign it in  AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: can i make differnt theme For Two Actiivties?

Comment: in application manifest no need to set any theme?  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme" >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82921/discussion-between-kumar-and-jack-wang).